# How do I get a list of timezone names of a browser

Tags: ios, windows, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I want to get the browser specific timezone names (different browsers displays different text for each system setting) for system available time zones. I need the exact string of the timezone that are in the "()" when writing console.error(new Date()) but not just for my current settings, without changing my OS settings and restarting the browser each time.

AFAIK js libraries uses their own name lists to solve this but the resulting names are different from the browser timezone name. I need the name as the browser will write it.

Thanks.

Comment: Javascript has no concept of timezone - only an offset number.  You would have to use a javascript library (or your own hardcoded values) to convert each offset number to a bit of text (e.g. "0 = GMT"). See http://joshowens.me/dealing-with-timezones-in-javascript/

Comment: Since I can get a timezone name when displaying a given date (I know it's coming from the browser, and Chrome and Firefox returns different names) I thought it may be possible to get the list of the browser - the way it translates the system timezones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was not possible when the question was asked, but with the [Intl.supportedValuesOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/supportedValuesOf) it is possible in modern engines:

```
console.log(Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone'));
```

At the time of this writing, you can ask for "calendar", "collation", "currency","numberingSystem", "timeZone" and "unit".

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Firefox v36 is showing the name but I guess I can't count on it in older versions.I was not able to verify that the name is taken from the system, but if so its enough for me. thanks.

Comment: I'm running Firefox V36.0.4 on windows and do only get "Thu Apr 02 2015 14:07:06 GMT-0235"

Comment: Try new Date().toString()

Comment: @RoyBen-Sasson That's exactly what I did.

Answer (score 1):

`Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone')` now provides the list of all available timezones on some browsers, including Safari and Chrome for iOS [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_intl_supportedvaluesof).